# Reorganise Stored Procedures display in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently working with an Asp.NET web application which involves a lot of stored procedures.

Since I'm also using the Asp.NET Membership/Roles/Profile system, the list of stored procedures displayed in the Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio is really becoming something of a pest to navigate. As soon as I open the `Programmability/Stored Procedures` tree, I have a long list of `dbo.aspnet_spXXX` stored procedures with my procedures loitering at the end.

What I would like to do is shuffle all those aspnet stored procedures into a folder of their own, leaving mine floating loose as they are now. I don't want to dispense with the current organisation, I just want to refine it a little.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can do in SSMS is to use a filter to exclude the aspnet stored procedures.

- Right click the Stored Procedures folder
- Select Filter -> Filter Settings
- Filter by Name, Does not contain, 'aspnet_sp'.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks so much! Will accept when I am allowed to (have to wait three minutes apparantly?)

Comment: @inksmithy while I have no problems with you accepting this answer, you do not necessarily need to accept an answer at the very first moment that you are allowed to do so. Even though this answer might ultimately be the best answer, it can sometimes be beneficial to wait before accepting. Once an answer has been accepted, the question is unlikely to gather any more traffic, and you could be forfeiting a better answer that might have come otherwise. Again, not saying that a better answer is likely here, just commenting on the "I must accept immediately" attitude in general.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Understood, thanks. I would ordinarily leave it a little longer, but this answer provided exactly what I was looking for pretty much instantly. Completely understand your point though.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend redgate's SQL search tool - handy for finding a particular proc, rather than scrolling through a large list.  Allows you to double click and go to it:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: That looks like a damn useful tool, I'll be using that one, thanks! Not quite what I was looking for, but a valuable tip nonetheless.

Comment: No problem. Not really a direct answer, but something that's definitely worth having.

Answer (score 2):

Management Studio doesn't support the ability to sort these objects other than alphabetically.

I like the filter and 3rd party add-in ideas, but another idea you can explore is using a different schema for your objects. If you name the schema 'abc' or something more logical, they will always sort first and none of your users will have to apply the filter.

```
CREATE SCHEMA abc AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO
ALTER SCHEMA abc TRANSFER dbo.proc1;
ALTER SCHEMA abc TRANSFER dbo.proc2;
ALTER SCHEMA abc TRANSFER dbo.proc3;
...
```

Of course you will need to update your code to reference this schema and you should also change all of your users' default schema.

This isn't really one of the primary purposes of schemas, but short of putting your objects in a different database, this is one way to visually separate them.

Comment: You are right, this is another useful approach. While I can't really change the current schema I'm working on, I can certainly take this approach next time. Thanks very much.